# How to avoid the need to double-tap the tab bar in xcode

Tags: view, double, hierarchy, tap, tabbarcontroller

I have two tabs in my project - one tab covers English soccer teams, the other covers German soccer teams.

In the English-soccer-team-tab, there's a hierachy of views: Firstly, a view controller with a list of English clubs, secondly if you tap on, for instance, Liverpool FC you'll go to a view controller with a list of players, and thirdly if you tap on a certain player you'll go to a view controller with information about this particular player.

Let's say I've tapped on Luis Suarez from Liverpool FX and then decide I'd like to find out something about a German team instead. In that case, I'll of course tap the tab bar item that says 'German soccer teams' and then browse around.

If I then want to return to English soccer and tap the 'English soccer teams'-tab I'm taken directly back to 'where I left the tab originially' (in this case, the view with all the info on Luis Suarez). To get to the 'first view controller' (the list of English teams) I have to double-tap the tab bar item.

My question is this: is it possible to go directly to the first view controller (the list of English teams) without having to do the double-tap when coming from another tab bar item???

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems. You must have a app delegate class where you are declaring the tab bar controller. You need to implement the following tab bar controller delegate method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
    {       
        int tabitem = tabBarController.selectedIndex;
        [[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:tabitem] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
```